# change div to increase progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I'm working to have my progress bar increase when a specific word is said (Bingo)
This is a conversation between a user and a chatbot, where the user is trying to guess a secret that the chatbot olds. Every time the user gets it right, the chatbot replies with "Bingo! " I was hoping to increase the progress bar every time the chatbot replies with "Bingo! " and when the progress bare hits 100% it should restart back to 0%. I get the progress bar shows, but it does not increase. I was thinking of having to loop through the div to look for "Bingo" and change the div in the progress bar. Or simply have a "Bingo" as a variable and match it to the div="bingo1" and then increase the progress bar. What would be the most efficient way?
[image]

I'm using chatterbot which contains the conversation between the user and chatbot in a .yml file, so it is possible to do something there

```js
function myBingo(){
  if (document.getElementById('bingo1').innerHTML.indexOf("Bingo")){ 
    // change progress bar to 10%
  } 
}
```

```css
#progress {
 width: 500px;   
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 padding: 3px;
}
#percent {
 position: absolute;   
 left: 50%;
}
#bar {
 height: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- I added an id here -->
<div class="msg-text" id="bingo1">Bingo! The secret is Garfield</div>

<div id="progress">
    <span id="percent">0%</span>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He might have given a different answer as he didn't quite understand what he wanted. In the solution below, the progress bar will be increased by the number of `Bingo` expressions entered into the item whose `id` value is `bingo1`.

*If you're asking something different, please edit the question or comment below this answer.*

[image]

```js
let percent = document.getElementById('percent');
let bar = document.getElementById('bar');
let input = document.getElementById('bingo1');
let counter = 0;

function update() {
  if (input.value.indexOf("Bingo") != -1)
  { 
    var count = (input.value.match(/Bingo/g) || []).length;
    counter = count * 10;
    
    if(counter >= 100)
      counter = 100;
      
    percent.innerHTML = `${counter}%`;
    bar.style.width = `${counter}%`;
  } 
}

input.addEventListener('input', update);
```

```css
#progress {
 width: 500px;   
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 padding: 3px;
}

#percent {
 position: absolute;   
 left: 50%;
}

#bar {
 height: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<label>Input: </label>
<input class="msg-text" id="bingo1"><br><br>

<div id="progress">
    <span id="percent">0%</span>
    <div id="bar"></div>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. But instead of typing "Bingo", it should just update automatically when seeing "Bingo" and reset back to 0 after reaching 100% with a prompt telling the user 100% is reached:                                                                                   
 function Fullvalue(){
  if (update()==100){
    prompt("100% reached") ;                                                                                                                      // rest progress bar to 0%
  }
}
</script>

Comment: In short, if the elementId "bingo1" exsists increas the progress bar by 10%. if the progress bar is full give the user a prompt and reset the progress bar back to 0%                           function exist() {
    //If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
if(typeof(input) != 'undefined' && input != null){
    update();
    //alert('Element exists');
} else{
  alert('Element does not exist');
}